# Fullscreen video to open website and dissolve

Tags: javascript

I would like a Youtube video opener (26 seconds, fades to black,then a 4 second tail of black) to automatically play full screen when going to a website and after the 26 seconds dissolve into the home page.  Would the video have to be on it's own page or on the home page in order for the dissolve to work?

Answer (score 0):

You would embed the YouTube video on the page. With CSS set it to:

```
position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
```

You can handle the timer with JavaScript, handle the fading with CSS opacity with a transition (starting at opacity: 1.0 and then when you want it to fade set it to opacity: 0).

And then after 30 seconds you could have another JS timer that removes it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove the image in the `main.css > #loader`, embed the video and  change the time to 26 seconds.

For this to work with Internet Explorer I also had to change from `#loader` to `#loader:before`  (I've used content).

It is a great preloading page, it is working perfectly for me. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/).